# How to remove invoice, shipment and creditmemo from Admin grid in magento1.9.0.1 programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, shipment, delete

I want to delete order programmatically. So I want to delete sales order from `sales->orders` grid as well as `sales->invoices` grid, `sales->shipments` grid. For that, I got a link [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18714/what-is-the-best-way-to-delete-a-magento-order) These site's code is not working on Invoice Delete and on Shipment Delete in Magento1.9.0.1 programmatically. it only deletes the order from `sales->order` list, not invoice from sales->invoices and not delete shipment from `sales->shipments`. I search a lot in google, but there is no suitable result "`How to delete invoice and shipment and creditmemo programmatically in Magento 1.9.0.1`".If any one knows about this issue, please reply it.

Answer (score 5):

I have got a success after long process/RND and searching on google a lot.

```
   $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', (array) $orderId);
                    foreach ($orders as $o) {
                        //load order object - I know it's not ok to use load in a loop but it should be ok since it's a one time script
                        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($o->getId());

                        $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
                        foreach ($invoices as $invoice){
                            //delete all invoice items
                            $items = $invoice->getAllItems(); 
                            foreach ($items as $item) {
                                $item->delete();
                            }
                            //delete invoice
                            $invoice->delete();
                        }
                        $creditnotes = $order->getCreditmemosCollection();
                        foreach ($creditnotes as $creditnote){
                            //delete all creditnote items
                            $items = $creditnote->getAllItems(); 
                            foreach ($items as $item) {
                                $item->delete();
                            }
                            //delete credit note
                            $creditnote->delete();
                        }
                        $shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
                        foreach ($shipments as $shipment){
                            //delete all shipment items
                            $items = $shipment->getAllItems(); 
                            foreach ($items as $item) {
                                $item->delete();
                            }
                            //delete shipment
                            $shipment->delete();
                        }
                        //delete all order items
                        $items = $order->getAllItems(); 
                        foreach ($items as $item) {
                            $item->delete();
                        }
                        //delete payment - not sure about this one
                        $order->getPayment()->delete();
                        //delete quote - this can be skipped
                        if ($order->getQuote()) {
                            foreach ($order->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
                                $item->delete();
                            }
                            $order->getQuote()->delete();
                        }
                        //delete order
                        $order->delete();

                        $order_increment_id = $order->getIncrementId();
                        /*if($order_increment_id){
                           $invoice_in_grid = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/invoice_grid_collection')->addFieldToFilter('increment_id',$order_increment_id);
                           $invoice_in_grid->delete(); 

                           $shipment_in_grid = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/shipment_grid_collection')->addFieldToFilter('increment_id',$order_increment_id);
                           $shipment_in_grid->delete(); 
                       }*/

                       $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                        $sales_flat_order_grid = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_order_grid');  
                        $sales_flat_invoice_grid = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_invoice_grid');
                        $sales_flat_shipment_grid = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_shipment_grid');
                        $order_increment_id = $o->getIncrementId();

                        if($order_increment_id)
                        { 
                        /*$query = "DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote WHERE reserved_order_id = ".$o->getId()."; 
                                  DELETE FROM sales_flat_invoice WHERE increment_id = ".$o->getId().";
                                  DELETE FROM sales_flat_invoice_grid WHERE order_id = ".$o->getId().";
                                  DELETE FROM sales_flat_shipment WHERE order_id = ".$o->getId().";
                                  DELETE FROM sales_flat_shipment_grid WHERE order_id = ".$o->getId().";";*/

                        $sql = "DELETE FROM ".$sales_flat_order_grid." WHERE increment_id='".mysql_escape_string($order_increment_id)."';
                                DELETE FROM ".$sales_flat_invoice_grid." WHERE order_id='".mysql_escape_string($o->getId())."'; 
                                DELETE FROM ".$sales_flat_shipment_grid." WHERE order_id='".mysql_escape_string($o->getId())."'";

                        /*$sql = "DELETE FROM ".$sales_flat_invoice_grid." WHERE order_id='".mysql_escape_string($o->getId())."'; 
                                DELETE FROM ".$sales_flat_shipment_grid." WHERE order_id='".mysql_escape_string($o->getId())."'";*/

                        //$db->query("DELETE FROM ".$sales_flat_invoice_grid." WHERE increment_id='".mysql_escape_string($order_increment_id)."'");        
                        $db->query($sql);
                        }
                        //exit;
                        //echo "deleted";
                    }   

                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Order was successfully deleted.'));
```

This code successfully deletes the order from Sales->Orders Grid, also deletes the invoice from Sales->invoices Grid, and also deletes shipment from Sales->Shipment Grid. For that, some portion it has been deleted from Database tables directly, not with magento code like ...->delete(); I need the code of Magento to delete order, invoice, shipment, also creditmemo from Grid. If any one knows about it, please reply it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to load them each individually, namely:

- `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);`
- `Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoice_id);`
- `Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipment_id);`
- `Mage::getModel('sales/order_creditmemo')->load($creditmemo_id);`

The aforementioned ids are stored in the `entity_id` column of these tables respectively:

- `sales_flat_order`,
- `sales_flat_invoice`,
- `sales_flat_shipment`,
- `sales_flat_creditmemo`

Alternately, you will see them in the URL for the order, invoice, shipment or creditmemo page itself, `/id/your_id_here/...`.

Once you've loaded the models, you can call the `->delete();` function on each one. Calling `$order->delete();` will not delete associated invoices from your database as a method to maintain data integrity.

Comment: "I have used these code like $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($o->getId());$invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
      //print_r($invoices->getData());
      foreach ($invoices as $invoice){
       $invoiceDet = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoice->getEntityId());
       
        $invoiceitems = $invoiceDet->getAllItems(); //print_r($invoiceitems);
       foreach ($invoiceitems as $invoiceitem) {
        $invoiceitem->delete();
}
//delete invoice
$invoiceDet->delete();}" But invoice is not deleting. I can not understand where I am wrong.